# Proving Equivalence of DFA and NFA

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

Im trying to learn Equivalence of DFA and NFA.The problem is that in the below explanation  Q' is given as the power set of Q.But this statement seems to be contradictory to the previous statement saying NFA is mapped from Q*E to 2^Q,Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing at all contradictory. $Q'$ is defined to be $2^Q$, the power set of $Q$. There is no mention of $E$ at all. My best guess is that you mean $\Sigma$, the input alphabet. If that’s the case, the map from $Q\times\Sigma$ to $2^Q$ is $\delta$, the transition function for the NFA $M$: for any state $q\in Q$ and $a\in\Sigma$, $\delta(q,a)$ is a **set** of states of $M$, i.e., a subset of $Q$. Specifically, $\delta(q,a)$ is the set of states $p$ such that there is an $a$-transition from $q$ to $p$.

This is one of the differences between DFAs and NFAs. If $Q$ is the set of states of an NFA with input alphabet $\Sigma$, the transition function for the NFA is a function from $Q\times\Sigma$ to $2^Q$: for each $a\in\Sigma$ there is a **set** of $a$-transitions out of each $q\in Q$. If, however, $Q$ is the set of states of a DFA with input alphabet $\Sigma$, the transition function for the DFA is a function from $Q\times\Sigma$ to $Q$: for each $a\in\Sigma$ there is exactly **one** $a$-transition out of each state $q\in Q$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Yeah i mean Σ.I Understand that The difference between NFA and DFA is the presense/absense of more than one transition on the same input symbol.As you have mentioned for NFA -> Q×Σ to 2^Q.But in the above example you can see that it is given as M' is the DFA and Q'is associated with the DFA not the NFA.is this a mistake in the textbook.

Comment: @techno: There is no mistake. $M'$ is a DFA, and $Q'=2^Q$ is its state set, where $Q$ is the state set of the original NFA. The individual states of the DFA $M'$ are the sets of states of the NFA $M$.

Comment: I dont have that much knowledge to understand this stuff.Any way im marking your's as right answer